# How can I get remote video width and height in webrtc

Tags: webrtc

I understand I can set width and height as constraints for local video. However, I'm not sure how to get the remote video width and height through an RTCPeerConnection. I googled quite a bit but it seems I didn't get any useful information. I think this should be a common question, so I guess I might have missed the direction. Sorry I'm new to webrtc.

The reason I want to get remote video size is that I want to keep the aspect ratio correct and show it in a local div, so that the remote video is not going to be stretched.

Edit:

It seems `video.videoWidth` and `video.videoHeight` are what I was looking for. However, I got both `0` in the `ontrack` callback. However, I could get the correct sizes in the chrome inspector after the video started to play for a while. I still haven't figured out when these values started to be available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `videoWidth` and `videoHeight` and listen for the `onsize`/`onresize` events of the video element as well as the `loadedmetadata`. See [here](https://github.com/webrtc/samples/blob/bdd6a6ee0e49f5ef9c8358f91f78e47b389f77aa/src/content/capture/canvas-pc/js/main.js#L25-L40) in one of the official webrtc samples and note that the video width can change if the encoder needs to adapt to low-bandwidth situations.

Comment: Thank you so much. That exactly answered my question.